# how to concat two csv file and then sort by python

Tags: python, sorting, csv, pandas, concatenation

I have two .csv files named all_cv.csv and common_cv.csv files. First I have concat this two csv files by pandas, and then save the data into a new file named join_cv_common.csv by pandas. After that I sorted the join_cv_common.csv file by pandas as below, and stored data are stored into a new file named sorted_cv_common.csv. I want to rewrite these two functions of pandas - concat and sort by pure python (2.6 and 3.4). Can someone help me in this regards? Thank you very much.

## Pandas concat function

```
cv = pd.read_csv('all_cv.csv')

ac = pd.read_csv('common_cv.csv')

merged = pd.concat([cv, ac])

merged.to_csv('join_cv_common.csv')
```

## Pandas sorting function

```
df = pd.read_csv('join_cv_common.csv')

df = df.sort(["adv_id", "conv_id"])

df.to_csv('sorted_cv_common.csv')
```

Comment: Any reason you don't sort prior to writing to csv?

Comment: Let me clarify: do you want to "rewrite `pandas.concat` and `pandas.sort` in pure Python"? What is preventing you from using the implementations within `pandas`? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

### Using the file i/o and list sorting

By my knowledge it can be done by reading both the files using the file i/o after that just join and convert the string to a list after that sort the newly created list and put it in the final output csv by converting the list to a string.
Following is the code implementation for that.

123.csv

> 1,a
>
> 2,b
>
> 4,d

456.csv

> 3,c
>
> 5,d

Read csv file in d1 and d2 using file open function

```
d = d1 + '\n' +  d2
lst = d.split('\n')
data = "\n".join(sorted(lst))
```